# Emacs Lisp (void-variable fPath)

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following piece of Lisp to change the line ending of a given file.

```
(defun change-eol (fPath, sysName)
  (let (myBuffer)
    (setq myBuffer (find-file fPath))
    (set-buffer-file-coding-system sysName)
    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer myBuffer)
   )
)


(change-eol "/home/user/foo.txt" 'mac)
```

When I execute it, I keep getting this error:

`Symbol's value as variable is void: fPath`

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: There should be no comma after fPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a comma after the fPath argument of your function change-oel, remove it and the function works as expected.